# Probability that the bus will arrive within 4-5 minutes

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

The bus runs at intervals of 10 minutes, and at a random moment you come to a stop. What is the probability that the bus will arrive within 4-5 minutes? My textbook says the answer is $\frac{1}{10}$ but i don't understand why. I understand why probability that the bus will arrive within 1 minute is $\frac{1}{10}$, cause there are 10 outcomes of which one is positive. But in case of 4-5 minutes there are 2 positive cases, so it must be $\frac{2}{10}=\frac{1}{5}$. Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Apparently "within 4-5 minutes" is to be interpreted as "the waiting time is at least 4 minutes and at most 5 minutes". So we still talk about a (different) one-minute interval

Comment: By "the bus runs at intervals of $10$ minutes" do you mean every $10$ minutes, on the dot? Or that the bus arrives according to a Poisson process with rate $6$ per hour?

Answer (score 3):

You must focus on the single *interval* $[4,5]$ and not on the two *points* $\{4,5\}$.

There are $10$ almost disjoint and covering subintervals of the form $[i,i+1]$ (where $i$ is an integer) for $[0,10]$ and they are equiprobable when it concerns the question whether the arrival time of the bus will fall in them.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm consistently getting a mean of about $\frac1{10}$ with a simulation:

```
# Number of busses
N <- 10000
# Bus arrivals
B <- rep(10, N)
# Your arrivals
X <- B - runif(N, 0, 10)
# Output results
hist(X)
cat(length(which(X>4 & X< 5)) / N)
```